Signal Detection in Noise
I have known pulses, e.g. $A\exp(-\frac{t}{\tau})\cos(\omega t)$, but they are "hidden" in additive (let's say Gaussian) noise and it is not possible to predict when such events will occur. The amplitude varies, but the frequency and time constant are more or less stable (change slowly with time). The noise can be much greater than the amplitude. Other signals than the above are possible (but all can be modelled).  In the end, I am mainly interested in the parameters of the signal (amplitude, frequency, time constant).
How could I detect and locate such signals in the noise? My first thought would be to use the cross-correlation between the known signal and the noise. But are there any "better" options than that? Maybe something with a Kalman filter or something?

The matched filter is the optimal linear filter for maximizing SNR in the presence of AWGN

Your function is an exponentially decaying sinusoid, can you do Fourier transform?

To determine where your modes occur, check out the AIC and MDL criterion. For a single, damped, real-valued sinusoid, the number of complex, damped modes is 2.
If you know (or have estimated) where the modes start, this is a modal analysis problem of detecting the mode frequencies, damping factors, and amplitudes. Typical approaches for this involve rank reduction on a Hankel data set, followed by min-norm Prony or Matrix Pencil (or total-least-squares Matrix Pencil, aka ESPRIT) for damped tones. The MUSIC algo can also be used, though it's usually presented for estimating undamped tones. My personal preference for direct evaluation is Matrix Pencil, and if I need best performance I'd consider the total-least-squares version.
Fundamentally, consider what triggers these events. Are they non-overlapping system responses to impulses or steps in a linear system, or might they overlap? Could you use multiple occurrences to get more coherence of signal? Doing so would help the above modal methods but requires additional insight for how to set up the data matrices.
